# Row was updated or deleted by another transaction or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect

Tags: java, hibernate

i am working on hibernate queries

the db has college(parent) and user(child)..user already stored in the db.

user has childs addresses,contacts

transaction A:

here the data will be fetched from db with college and user and then updates the college.

when a user change from one college to other...transaction A will update the college by fetching the college table and updates as follows.In such case only college Id will be updated in user table by parent(which is college)

```
user.setCollege(college);
saveorupdate(college)
```

trasaction B:

saveorupdate one parent(user) and their child into database..(User has addresses,contacts).......updating the user with addresses and contacts individually..

with Transaction B alone it is working fine..

with tranaction A and then complete the transaction A and then start the new transaction with B...

Here it is saying the Row was already updated by another transaction for contacts

Comment: Are these in the same `Session`?

Comment: @bmorris591 No...as i used Transactional annotation for service layer as trnsaction a and transaction b are in different methods...these methods are called by delegate one after the other...so i think the transactions are in different session..

Comment: i updated my question with some more details..thanks

Comment: It looks like the second transaction is working with stale data, data that is not aware of the first transaction. Try calling `session.refresh(user)` before beginning the process to reload from the database. That isn't really a solution but it will illustrate the problem.